# How much rays can be drawn..?

Tags: combinatorics

Q: How many many *rays* can be drawn from $n$ numbers of *bars*? (generalization)

**First** let us define a **Nomenclature**,
"$D_b$ tells us the number of *rays* that should be drawn and ,$b$ tells us the number of bars."

What do you mean by **bars and rays**?
[image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21raf.png)

The rule is such that , only *downward rays are allowed* (rays originate from bars, bars are black and rays are red)

So for $b=x$ we will count like, rays from bar 1+rays from  bar+ rays from  2 + rays from bar 3+... till rays from *x th* bar

So, for eg- $b=1,2,3,4\dots$

$D_1=0  ,D_2=1,D_3=3,D_4=6$ and so on

We want to find when $D_x$ and make a generalization...

Comment: Hint: When you add an extra bar, how many extra rays do you get? Why?

Comment: @Henry, thank you for the hint. I got my answer. Please consider upvoting my post.

Answer (score 1):

The total number of lines from $n$ number of bars is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{b-1} {n} $$

where $b$ is the number of bars.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).